# How I can upload pictures using multer for array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multer

I am using nodeJS, express and mongoose. I am having a schema of form which also uploads multiple pictures. To upload the pictures I am using multer. In multer, I am using multer.fields() to upload the pic with specific own name of key to upload the pic like father_pic, mother_pic and brother_pic. Now Issue is that, There can be more than one brother so How I can upload multiple pictures for the brother pic related to his name and profession?

**Model Schema**

```js
const familyDetailsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        language:{
            type:String,
            require:true
        },
        father:{
            fatherName:{
                type:String,
                require:true
            },
            fatherProfession:{
                type:String,
                require:true
            },
            fatherImage:{
                type:String,
                require:true
            }
        },  
        mother:{
            motherName:{
                type:String,
                require:true
            },
            motherProfession:{
                type:String,
                require:true
            },
            motherImage:{
                type:String,
                require:true
            }
        },
        brothers:[
            {
                name:String,
                profession:String,
                image:String,
            }
        ],
        details:{
            type:String,
            require:true
        },
        user_id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Number
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: Number,
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps:true,
    }
)
```

**Here's the code of route**

```js
router.post('/familyDetails',
    [
        upload.fields([
            {
                name: 'father_pic',
                
            },
            {
                name: 'mother_pic',
                
            },
            {
                name:'brother_pic'
            }
        ]),
    ],

    async (req, res) => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

To treat this input as array you can use multer.array, follow this simple example:

```
router.post('/family',
    [
        upload.array('family_pictures'),
    ],

async (req, res) => {
    const images = req.files['family_pictures'];

    images.forEach((image) => {

    });
  }
);
```

To understand with more details you can use multer docs at npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using `.any()` method of the Multer, that will enable you to upload files with any name. Then, you don't have to worry about the number of files and the file names.

```js
router.post('/familyDetails', upload.any(), async (req, res) => {
  
  console.log('Files: ', req.files);

})
```